# When is the new gnome destop enviroment going to be released as the default desktop enviroment?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

This is a simple question, so please give a simple answer.

I have heard that the very impressive new Gnome desktop environment will be released soon to take the place of unity.

Could anyone tell me which Ubuntu version it will be/is being released in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of Ubuntu is 17.04 (zesty) and the next version is 17.10 (Artful Aardvark), which will be released with Gnome desktop environment at 19th October [[1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)] [[2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseSchedule)].